# What was the first song to contain a sample from another song on the same album?

Tags: history, rap, sample

Listening to Public Enemy's *It Takes a Nation of Millions to Hold Us Back* (1988) and noticed that "Night of the Living Baseheads" contains a few samples from "Bring the Noise" from the same album (e.g. Chuck D saying "Base!").  Was this the first instance of this happening or is there an earlier example where a song samples a different song found on the same album?

Comment: In the Rap/Hip Hop genre specifically or in any genre? Because there are lots of examples where a band thought it was an original idea to make the last track of an album containing a mix of all/some tracks present on the album. Earliest I can think of off the top of my head is _Queen - More of that Jazz_, last track of the album _Jazz_ (1978). But I'm sure there are much earlier examples.